# Implementing LoadMore functionality with paging library 2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library

i have implemented paging library in my application which is working pretty fine , now the functionality that i want to add is to simply show load more as progress bar in the bottom , so when there isn't data , simply show progress bar , now i'm getting confused on what to use either normal pagination with recycler view where i need to check for last position in the layout manager or simply use view item type with recycler , your help is appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The concept of load state isn't build into Paging v2 APIs - you need to track this yourself via posting updates from your implementation of `DataSource` and the easiest way to show another load state based item in `RecyclerView` is with `ConcatAdapter`.

However if you are inclined to upgrade to the v3 beta, the good news is that this is supported out of the box with the v3 APIs - see:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#loadStateFlow:kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

and:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/LoadStateAdapter